# Flutter : Viewports expand in the cross axis to fill their container and constrain their children to match their extent in the cross axis

Tags: android, flutter, widget, flutter-layout

I am trying to convert one native android application into flutter to make it support for **iOS** and **web**. I have created and make application as per requirement but I am facing issue at one page and it's home page of application. Here I am sharing you the design of that page below.

[image: Home Page of my application]

Here is I am sharing you the code for that page in dart language as well.

Dart Version used: `sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"`

**home_screen.dart:**

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => HomeState();
}

class HomeState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  String whatsAppNo = "";
  String pinCode = "";

  bool isLoading = false;
  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  Widget _buildProgressIndicator() {
    return new Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: new Center(
        child: new Opacity(
          opacity: isLoading ? 1.0 : 00,
          child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      _afterLayout(context);
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  _afterLayout(BuildContext context) async {
    CategoryProvider _categoryProvider = Provider.of<CategoryProvider>(context, listen: false);
    await _categoryProvider.getCategoryDetails();

    ProductProvider _productProvider = Provider.of<ProductProvider>(context, listen: false);
    await _productProvider.getProductList(
      jurisdictionId: "4",
      categoryId: "45",
      subCategoryId: "-1",
      filter: "0",
      searchProductId: "-1",
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final categoryProvider = Provider.of<CategoryProvider>(context);
    final productProvider = Provider.of<ProductProvider>(context);

    Widget pinCode() {
      return FittedBox(
        fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
        child: TextButton.icon(
          icon: Image.asset(
            Assets.ic_pin,
            color: AppColor.white,
            width: 24.0,
            height: 24.0,
          ),
          style: ButtonStyle(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          ),
          label: Text(
            "Delivered to ${pinCode}",
            style: regularTextStyle(
              textColor: AppColor.white,
              textSize: Dimens.txt_size_fifteen,
            ),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            print("Click on PinCode");
          },
        ),
      );
    }

    Widget reorder() {
      return FittedBox(
        fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextButton(
              child: Text(
                Strings.btn_reorder,
                style: regularTextStyle(
                  textColor: AppColor.white,
                  textSize: Dimens.txt_size_fifteen,
                ),
              ),
              style: ButtonStyle(
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                print("Reorder button");
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }

    Widget pinCodeReorderBar() {
      return Container(
        color: AppColor.colorPrimary,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 64,
              child: pinCode(),
            ),
            WidgetUtils.verticalDivider(AppColor.white),
            Expanded(
              flex: 36,
              child: reorder(),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
    }

    Widget filterButton() {
      return FittedBox(
        fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
        child: TextButton.icon(
          icon: Image.asset(
            Assets.ic_sort,
            width: 24.0,
            height: 24.0,
          ),
          style: ButtonStyle(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
          ),
          label: Text(
            Strings.sort,
            style: regularTextStyle(
                textColor: AppColor.colorPrimary,
                textSize: Dimens.txt_size_fifteen),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            print("Filter Button");
          },
        ),
      );
    }

    Widget confirmButton() {
      return FittedBox(
        fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text(
            "1 Product Added | ${Strings.btn_confirm_order}",
            style: regularTextStyle(
              textColor: AppColor.white,
              textSize: Dimens.txt_size_fifteen,
            ),
          ),
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            onPrimary: AppColor.colorPrimary,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            ),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            print("Confirm button");
          },
        ),
      );
    }

    Widget filterConfirmBar() {
      return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 3,
              child: filterButton(),
            ),
            //Utils.verticalDivider(AppColor.colorPrimary),
            Expanded(
              flex: 7,
              child: confirmButton(),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
    }

    Widget getCircularProgressIndicator() {
      return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(
          8.0,
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Opacity(
            opacity: 1.0,
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    Widget buildCategoryList() {
      return Container(
        child: categoryProvider.loadingCategory
            ? getCircularProgressIndicator()
            : ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: categoryProvider.categoryList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return CategoryItem(
                    category: categoryProvider.categoryList[index],
                    onCategorySelect: (category) => {
                      categoryProvider.updateCategorySelectedValue(
                        index,
                        category,
                      ),
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
      );
    }

    Widget buildSubCategoryList() {
      return Container(
        child: categoryProvider.loadingCategory
            ? getCircularProgressIndicator()
            : ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: categoryProvider.subCategoryList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return SubCategoryItem(
                    subCategory: categoryProvider.subCategoryList[index],
                    onSubCategorySelect: (subCategory) => {
                      categoryProvider.updateSubCategorySelctedValue(
                        index,
                        subCategory,
                      )
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
      );
    }

    Widget buildProductList() {
      return productProvider.loadingProduct
          ? getCircularProgressIndicator()
          : productProvider.productList != null &&
                  productProvider.productList.isNotEmpty
              ? ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: productProvider.productList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    try {
                      Product product = productProvider.productList[index];

                      switch (product.itemType) {
                        case "1":
                          return ProductItem(
                            product: productProvider.productList[index],
                            onProductValueChange: (product) => {
                              print("Product: ${product.toString()}"),
                            },
                          );

                        case "2":
                        case "3":
                          return BannerItem(
                            product: productProvider.productList[index],
                            onProductValueChange: (product) => {
                              print("Product: ${product.toString()}"),
                            },
                          );

                        default:
                          return Container();
                      }
                    } catch (e) {
                      return Text("Product Item Loading: ${e.toString()}");
                    }
                  },
                )
              : Center(
                  child: Text(productProvider.message),
                );
    }

    Future<bool> _onBackPressed() async {
      return (await showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(
              title: new Text('Are you sure?'),
              content: new Text('Do you want to exit an App'),
              actions: <Widget>[
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
                  child: new Text('No'),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
                  child: new Text('Yes'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )) ??
          false;
    }

    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _onBackPressed,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: HomeAppBar(
          whatsAppNo: whatsAppNo,
        ),
        drawer: DrawerMenu(),
        body: Container(
          color: AppColor.white,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              pinCodeReorderBar(),
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: buildCategoryList(),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: buildSubCategoryList(),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 9,
                child: buildProductList(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: filterConfirmBar(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**category_item.dart**

```
class CategoryItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final Category category;
  final ValueChanged<Category> onCategorySelect;

  CategoryItem({this.category, this.onCategorySelect});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _CategoryItemState();
}

class _CategoryItemState extends State<CategoryItem> {
  static const double category_image_size = 50.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      child: Wrap(
        alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 75.0,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              left: 5.0,
              right: 5.0,
            ),
            color: AppColor.white,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                widget.category.categoryImage != null &&
                        widget.category.categoryImage.isNotEmpty
                    ? CachedNetworkImage(
                        imageUrl: widget.category.categoryImage,
                        width: category_image_size,
                        height: category_image_size,
                        imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                              image: imageProvider,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          ),
                        ),
                        placeholder: (context, url) => Image.asset(
                          Assets.image_placeholder,
                          width: category_image_size,
                          height: category_image_size,
                        ),
                        errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Image.asset(
                          Assets.no_image_available,
                          width: category_image_size,
                          height: category_image_size,
                        ),
                      )
                    : SizedBox(),

                widget.category.categoryName != null &&
                        widget.category.categoryName.isNotEmpty
                    ? AutoSizeText(
                        widget.category.categoryName,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: regularTextStyle(
                          textSize: Dimens.txt_size_twelve,
                          textColor: !widget.category.isSelected
                              ? Color(0xFF1A1A1A)
                              : AppColor.colorPrimary,
                          weight: !widget.category.isSelected
                              ? FontWeight.normal
                              : FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                        maxFontSize: Dimens.txt_size_twelve,
                        minFontSize: Dimens.txt_size_eight,
                        maxLines: 3,
                      )
                    : SizedBox(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      onTap: () {
        setState(
          () {
            widget.onCategorySelect(widget.category);
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**product_item.dart**

```
class ProductItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final Product product;
  final ValueChanged<Product> onProductValueChange;

  ProductItem({this.product, this.onProductValueChange});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _ProductItemState();
}

class _ProductItemState extends State<ProductItem> {
  static const product_image_size = 110.0;

  bool _isProductDescription() {
    if (widget.product.isProductDescription) {
      if ((widget.product.productDescription != null &&
              widget.product.productDescription.isNotEmpty) ||
          (widget.product.productKeyFeatures != null &&
              widget.product.productKeyFeatures.isNotEmpty) ||
          (widget.product.productNotes != null &&
              widget.product.productNotes.isNotEmpty)) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  bool _isSoshoRecommended() {
    if (widget.product.isSoshoRecommended) {
      if (widget.product.soshoRecommended != null &&
          widget.product.soshoRecommended.isNotEmpty) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  Attributes _getSelectedAttributes() {
    if (widget.product.attributesList != null &&
        widget.product.attributesList.isNotEmpty) {
      for (Attributes attribute in widget.product.attributesList) {
        attribute.saveRupees = attribute.mrp - attribute.soshoPrice;

        if (attribute.isSelected) {
          print("Selected Attribute is: ${attribute.toString()}");
          return attribute;
        }
      }
    } else {
      return Attributes();
    }
  }

  String _getProductName() {
    if (widget.product.productName != null &&
        widget.product.productName.isNotEmpty) {
      if (_getSelectedAttributes().packingType != null &&
          _getSelectedAttributes().packingType.isNotEmpty) {
        return widget.product.productName + ", " + _getSelectedAttributes().packingType;
      } else {
        return widget.product.productName;
      }
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  }

  Widget recommended() {
    return Visibility(
      visible: _isSoshoRecommended(),
      maintainState: true,
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            const Radius.circular(
              10.0,
            ),
          ),
          color: AppColor.colorPrimary,
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(
          5.0,
        ),
        child: Text(
          widget.product.soshoRecommended,
          style: regularTextStyle(
            textColor: AppColor.white,
            textSize: Dimens.txt_size_eight,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget productInfo() {
    return Visibility(
      visible: _isProductDescription(),
      maintainState: true,
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
          right: 5.0,
        ),
        child: Image.asset(
          Assets.ic_product_info,
          width: 40.0,
          height: 20.0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget soldCount() {
    return Visibility(
      visible: widget.product.soldCount != null &&
          widget.product.soldCount.isNotEmpty,
      child: Text(
        widget.product.soldCount,
        style: regularTextStyle(
          textColor: Color(0xff8f8f8f),
          textSize: Dimens.txt_size_ten,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget specialMessage() {
    return Visibility(
      visible: widget.product.isSpecialMessage &&
          widget.product.specialMessage != null &&
          widget.product.specialMessage.isNotEmpty,
      child: Container(),
    );
  }

  Widget productImage() {
    return Container(
        width: product_image_size,
        height: product_image_size,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
          left: 2.5,
          top: 15.0,
          bottom: 2.5,
        ),
        child: _getSelectedAttributes().aImageName != null &&
                _getSelectedAttributes().aImageName.isNotEmpty
            ? CachedNetworkImage(
                imageUrl: _getSelectedAttributes().aImageName,
                width: product_image_size,
                height: product_image_size,
                placeholder: (context, url) => Image.asset(
                  Assets.image_placeholder,
                  width: product_image_size,
                  height: product_image_size,
                ),
                errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Image.asset(
                  Assets.no_image_available,
                  width: product_image_size,
                  height: product_image_size,
                ),
              )
            : Image.asset(
                Assets.no_image_available,
                width: product_image_size,
                height: product_image_size,
              ));
  }

  Widget productName() {
    return Visibility(
      visible: widget.product.productName != null &&
          widget.product.productName.isNotEmpty,
      child: Text(
        _getProductName(),
        style: boldTextStyle(
          textColor: Color(0xff1a1a1a),
          textSize: Dimens.txt_size_sixteen,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget discount() {
    return Positioned(
      top: 5,
      left: 2.5,
      child: Visibility(
        visible: _getSelectedAttributes().discount != null &&
            _getSelectedAttributes().discount.isNotEmpty,
        maintainState: true,
        child: Container(
          width: 45.0,
          height: 45.0,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            color: Color(0xffb12704),
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: AutoSizeText(
              _getSelectedAttributes() != null &&
                      _getSelectedAttributes().discount != null
                  ? _getSelectedAttributes().discount
                  : "",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: boldTextStyle(
                textSize: Dimens.txt_size_fourteen,
                textColor: AppColor.white,
              ),
              maxLines: 2,
              maxFontSize: Dimens.txt_size_fourteen,
              minFontSize: Dimens.txt_size_eight,
              stepGranularity: 2,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget productPrice() {
    return Visibility(
      visible: _getSelectedAttributes().soshoPrice != 0.00,
      child: Text(
        "Sosho Price: ₹ ${_getSelectedAttributes().soshoPrice}",
        style: regularTextStyle(
          textColor: Color(0xff1a1a1a),
          textSize: Dimens.txt_size_fourteen,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget productMRP() {
    return Visibility(
      visible: _getSelectedAttributes().mrp != 0.00,
      child: Text(
        'MRP: ₹ ${_getSelectedAttributes().mrp}',
        style: regularTextStyle(
          textColor: Color(0xff8f8f8f),
          textSize: Dimens.txt_size_ten,
        ).copyWith(
          decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget saveRupee() {
    return Visibility(
      visible: _getSelectedAttributes().saveRupees != null,
      child: Text(
        'Save ₹ ${_getSelectedAttributes().saveRupees}',
        style: regularTextStyle(
          textColor: Color(0xff8f8f8f),
          textSize: Dimens.txt_size_ten,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget productVariantButton() {
    return Visibility(
      visible: !(widget.product.attributesList.length > 1),
      child: Center(
        child: AutoSizeText(
          _getSelectedAttributes() != null &&
                  _getSelectedAttributes().weight != null
              ? _getSelectedAttributes().weight
              : "",
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: regularTextStyle(
            textColor: AppColor.black,
            textSize: Dimens.txt_size_fourteen,
          ),
          maxFontSize: Dimens.txt_size_fourteen,
          minFontSize: Dimens.txt_size_ten,
          stepGranularity: 2,
        ),
      ),
      replacement: Container(
        height: 25.0,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(
          5.0,
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: AppColor.transparent,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
          border: Border.all(
            color: Color(0xFFD0D0D0),
          ),
        ),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            AutoSizeText(
              _getSelectedAttributes() != null &&
                      _getSelectedAttributes().weight != null
                  ? _getSelectedAttributes().weight
                  : "",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: regularTextStyle(
                textColor: AppColor.black,
                textSize: Dimens.txt_size_fourteen,
              ),
              maxFontSize: Dimens.txt_size_fourteen,
              minFontSize: Dimens.txt_size_ten,
              stepGranularity: 2,
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(
                2.5,
              ),
              child: Image.asset(
                Assets.ic_down_arrow,
                width: 20.0,
                height: 20.0,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget productAddQuantityButton() {
    return Visibility(
      visible: !_getSelectedAttributes().isProductAdded,
      child: Container(
        width: 100.0,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(
          5.0,
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: AppColor.colorPrimary,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
            5.0,
          ),
        ),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Text(
          Strings.buy_now,
          style: regularTextStyle(
            textColor: AppColor.white,
            textSize: Dimens.txt_size_fourteen,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget productPriceAndInfoBar() {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 5.0,
      ),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: productPrice(),
          ),
          productInfo(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget productMRPSaveRupeeAndSoldCount() {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 5.0,
      ),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: [
          productMRP(),
          saveRupee(),
          soldCount(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget productVariantQuantityAndAddButton() {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 5.0,
      ),
      height: 30.0,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: [
          productVariantButton(),
          productAddQuantityButton(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.maxFinite,
      color: AppColor.white,
      child: IntrinsicHeight(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: <Widget>[
            Stack(
              fit: StackFit.passthrough,
              children: <Widget>[
                productImage(),
                discount(),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 8.0,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 2.5,
                  bottom: 2.5,
                  top: 2.5,
                ),
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 2.5,
                  right: 2.5,
                ),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: [
                    recommended(),
                    productName(),
                    productPriceAndInfoBar(),
                    productMRPSaveRupeeAndSoldCount(),
                    productVariantQuantityAndAddButton(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the code which I have used to design the page shown in the image. And while I am running this code I am facing the error for rendering the views and it also occupy the memory more.

Error which I am getting at this page is as below:

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height.

Viewports expand in the cross axis to fill their container and constrain their children to match their extent in the cross axis. In this case, a horizontal viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand.
The relevant error-causing widget was:
ListView file:///D:/Development/Workspace/Flutter/Sosho_Flutter/sosho/lib/ui/page/home_page.dart:206:24

I have try all the way which are mention on other post on **StackOverFlow**, **Medium**, and **Github** (Flutter issue page). But I am not be able to find where actually this issue I am facing and how to resolve this issue.

Here, I am not be able to share 2 other class which are for **subcategory** and **banner** which are shown in the screen or you can be able to understand it easily from the screen.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: When I am trying to draw divider for the line below toolbar (White Color) and bottom last line (Blue Line) seen in the above image. It does not show the divider and also for bottom line divider it shows full screen divider. For that also I am not be able to find the solution also.

Comment: `The relevant error-causing widget was: ListView file:///D:/Development/Workspace/Flutter/Sosho_Flutter/sosho/lib/ui/page/home_page.dart:206:24` - are `home_screen.dart` and `home_page.dart` the same file? If not, could you update the question to include that?